# Sort list of strings ignoring upper/lower case

Tags: python, sorting, lexicographic, lexicographic-ordering

I have a list which contains strings representing animal names. I need to sort the list. If I use `sorted(list)`, it will give the list output with uppercase strings first and then lowercase.

But I need the below output.

Input:

```
var = ['ant','bat','cat','Bat','Lion','Goat','Cat','Ant']
```

Output:

```
['ant', 'Ant', 'bat', 'Bat', 'cat', 'Cat', 'Goat', 'Lion']
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The `sort()` method and the `sorted()` function take a key argument:

```
var.sort(key=lambda v: v.upper())
```

The function named in `key` is called for each value and the return value is used when sorting, without affecting the actual values:

```
>>> var=['ant','bat','cat','Bat','Lion','Goat','Cat','Ant']
>>> sorted(var, key=lambda v: v.upper())
['ant', 'Ant', 'bat', 'Bat', 'cat', 'Cat', 'Goat', 'Lion']
```

To sort `Ant` before `ant`, you'd have to include a little more info in the key, so that otherwise equal values are sorted in a given order:

```
>>> sorted(var, key=lambda v: (v.upper(), v[0].islower()))
['Ant', 'ant', 'Bat', 'bat', 'Cat', 'cat', 'Goat', 'Lion']
```

The more complex key generates `('ANT', False)` for `Ant`, and `('ANT', True)` for `ant`; `True` is sorted after `False` and so uppercased words are sorted before their lowercase equivalent.

See the [Python sorting HOWTO](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Martijin. Is ther way to get output also as ['Ant', 'ant', 'Bat', 'bat', 'Cat', 'cat', 'Goat', 'Lion']. I have tried var.sort(key=lambda v: v.lower()). It gives the same output

Comment: @PSivachandran: You have to add a little info to the key to make `Ant` sort before `ant`. Use `lamda v: (v.upper(), v[0].islower())` for example, as `True` is sorted after `False`.

Comment: Better use `sorted(var, key=lambda v: (v.upper(), v))`

Comment: @coldfix: that depends; is it a requirement that the lowercase version of a word comes before the same word with title caps even if their order in the original was swapped? Then yes, return a tuple.

Comment: OFC, but I think it's a bit of a stretch that someone would want to sort case-insensitively on the whole word and use the case of the first letter for edge cases but then suddenly stop there and use stability for the rest:) If someone were to write *that code* I'd be 99% sure that they actually wanted the simpler solution from my comment above which makes the order of the output deterministic from the set of input elements independent of their initial order (so you could e.g. use this to sort on `set`s etc). This is fulfilled netiher by `key=str.upper` nor by your last suggestion.

Comment: @coldfix There's also the possibility that they just wanted upper case versions to appear first, in which case `sorted(var, key=lambda v: (v.upper(), v.swapcase()))` might work well.

Answer (score 29):

New answer for Python 3, I'd like to add two points:

1. Use [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) for case-insensitive comparisons.
2. Use the method directly instead of inside of a lambda.

That is:

```
var = ['ant','bat','cat','Bat','Lion','Goat','Cat','Ant']

var.sort(key=str.casefold)
```

(which sorts in-place) and now:

```
>>> var
['ant', 'Ant', 'bat', 'Bat', 'cat', 'Cat', 'Goat', 'Lion']
```

Or, to return a new list, use `sorted`

```
>>> var = ['ant','bat','cat','Bat','Lion','Goat','Cat','Ant']
>>> sorted(var, key=str.casefold)
['ant', 'Ant', 'bat', 'Bat', 'cat', 'Cat', 'Goat', 'Lion']
```

Why is this different from `str.lower` or `str.upper`? [According to the documentation:](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold)

> Casefolding is similar to lowercasing but more aggressive because it is intended to remove all case distinctions in a string. For example, the German lowercase letter `'ß'` is equivalent to `"ss"`. Since it is already lowercase, `str.lower()` would do nothing to `'ß'`; `casefold()` converts it to `"ss"`.

Answer (score 7):

I need to add yet another answer, since both the accepted answer and the newer 
versions *lack one important thing*:

The here proposed case-insensitive sorting *is not stable* in the ordering of
"equal" keys!

That means: When you have a mixture of mixed case strings that you want to sort,
you get a correctly sorted list, but it is undefined whether "AbC" comes before
"aBc" or after. This may even vary between runs of the same program.

In order to always have the same output with a stable default ordering of strings,
I use the following function:

```
sorted(var, key=lambda v: (v.casefold(), v))
```

This way, the original key is always appended as a fallback ordering when the
casefold version does not supply a difference to sort on.